# How to show that $u_l(0)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, $u_l(1)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $u_l(n)= 0$ for $2 \leq n \leq (\frac{N}{2^{l-1}}-1$ $\dots$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that
$$u_1 = \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0,0,\ldots,0\right)\quad\text{and}\quad
v_1 = \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0,0,\ldots,0\right)$$
and 
$$u_l(n) = \sum_{k=0}^{2^{l-1}-1} u_1\left(n+ \frac{kN}{2^{l-1}}\right)\quad\text{and}\quad
v_l(n) = \sum_{k=0}^{2^{l-1}-1} v_1\left(n+ \frac{kN}{2^{l-1}}\right).$$
How to show that 
\begin{align*}
u_l(0)&=  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\\
u_l(1)&=  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\\
u_l(n)&=  0 &\quad&\text{for $2 \leq n \leq \frac{N}{2^{l-1}}-1$,}\\
v_l(0)&=  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\\
v_l(1)&=  -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\\
v_l(n)&=  0&&\text{for $2 \leq n \leq \frac{N}{2^{l-1}}-1$.}
\end{align*}

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: Are $u_1,v_1$ in $\mathbb{R}^N$? And apparently $2^{l-1}$ has to divide  $kN$ for $u_1(n+\frac{kN}{2^{l-1}})$ to make sense. The problem is not clear at all.

Comment: I’m stuck at following $u_l(0)= \sum_{k=0}^{2^{l-1}-1} u_1(0+ \frac{kN}{2^{l-1}}) = ? = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: What is $N$? What does $u_1(\cdot)$ mean? Does $u_1(k)$ mean the $k$th coordinate of $u_1$? Please clarify.

Comment: $N$ means that “it” is $\frac{N}{2^{l-1}}$-periodic( one must assume that $N$ is divisible by $2^p$. $u_1$ and $v_1$ form first stage Haar basis. Yes, $u_1(k) $ mean the $k$:th coordinate of $u_1$. Thus this is my clarification.